# Move Windows Phone contacts from phone to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I've managed to get contacts from my old phone to a new Windows Phone (I know, it's a work phone) via Bluetooth.

Now I can see the contacts under "People", but I want to move them to Outlook, so they can be synced to work email.

I can use the "filter contacts" option to show just the contacts that aren't synced, but that's as far as I've got. Under the menu, there is no "multiselect" option, nor is there any mention of "export" etc.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out:

- The contacts I thought I sent via Bluetooth were never actually received: when you receive a contact you are meant to click accept, then click save. However when setting many contacts at once, it doesn't give you a change to click save - because it immediately comes up with the accept button for the next one. A flaw in WP obviously.
- My organisations' IT manager's contacts were the ones showing up instead (don't ask me). I've managed to hide them now using the "Filter contacts" option.
- The solution was to connect the old phone to WiFi, copy all it's SIM contacts to outlook, sync it, disconnect it, then sync the new phone.